# Change android layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I start my application with a layout `main.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/applogo" ... android:src="@drawable/app_logo"/>
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" ... android:layout_below="@+id/applogo">
        <LinearLayout ...>
            <TabWidget.../>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"...>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the user in the settings menu can choose another layout, smaller (`tiny.xml`), whose layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relative" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost" ...>
        <LinearLayout ...>
            <TabWidget.../>
            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"...>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `mainActivity` extends `TabActivity` and in the `onCreate` method:

...

```
if (isTiny())
setContentView(R.layout.tiny);
else
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mTabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec newsTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec(NewsActivity.static_getTabActivityTag());
newsIntent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);      
newsTab.setContent(newsIntent);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);

textView.setText(getResources().getString(NewsActivity.static_getIndicatorStringID());
textView.setTextSize(size);
textView.setTextColor(color);
textView.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
tab.setIndicator(textView);
mTabHost.addTab(newsTab);
```

The idea is to write some code in `mainActivity#onRestart` so if the user changed the layout through the settings panel load the new layout for him. How to achieve it? I tried using `setContentView` <strike>but it just crashes</strike> and creating the views for the tabs again but it just do not work, the views are blank.

Updated: added how to create a tab in the Activity.

**Update** It is possible to do more than once setContentView. My problem was related to the activities in the Intent.

Comment: What's the stack trace of the crash? Calling `setContentView()` multiple times should be ok, but you need to re-bind any `View` references (i.e. run through `findViewById`) after doing so.

Comment: You can `setContentView` twice, but you need to re-initialize the View references after that (call the findViewById methods again for each View, add various listeners, etc.)

Comment: I've just checked and it does not crash, but the views don't work. Maybe is because I'm re-creating them instead of re-binding them?

Comment: It might help to post your activity, and I have to ask the ... aren't really in your layout files right?  That could be a problem.

Comment: The layout files are right. They work independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call setContentView at any time it doesn't have to be in onCreate.  I would used a`SharedPreferences` to store which content view the user wants.  Hope this helps.

Comment: You can only call setContentView once though

Comment: you can call it as many times as you want I have multiple projects that call setContentView outside of onCreate.  Edit: that being said both times it was a mistake to do it that way and I regretted it would have been better to use a separate activity.  In this case it may be better to use a Theme, but this may be an acceptable solution as well.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code of the activity that creates a tab. I hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For fragments layout I do it like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (MainActivity.isDarkMode) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dark, container, false);
    } else {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_light, container, false);
    }
}
```

So you get the idea.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make sure you are answering the question. "I do this" and "you get  the idea" along with a code snippet is really not an answer. Provide some explanation as to how the code snippet answers the question. See [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)