# How to change layout orientation in service on Android

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my application i want use one `service` and for this `service` i set **custom content layout**.
I want when **change screen orientation**, i want **change** this layout.
I write below codes, but when change screen orientation not change my layout!

**My Service codes:**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        //Inflate the layout using LayoutInflater
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        floatingLayout = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_layout, null);

  }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            Log.d("tag", "Portrait");
            floatingLayout = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_layout, null);

        } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.d("tag", "Landscape");
            floatingLayout = (ConstraintLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_layout_land, null);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change android layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451641/change-android-layout-programmatically)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati, thanks but i want detect on service , not activity

Comment: services are not for this purpose.